# Recent items with RibbonGallery: MVVM way to avoid last clicked item from remaining selected

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon

Actually it sounds like a basic question, but I could not find a proper MVVM way to keep the lastest clicked item from remaining selected.

I use a RibbonGallery to display a list of recently opened projects:

[image]

XAML:

```xml
<RibbonGallery Grid.Row         = "1"
               CanUserFilter    = "False"
               Command          = "{Binding cmdOpenRecent}"

               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto">

    <RibbonGalleryCategory Background   = "Transparent" 
                           ItemsSource  = "{Binding RecentProjects}">

        <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>

    </RibbonGalleryCategory>

</RibbonGallery>
```

When I select an entry, the command gets called and I can open the file.

The issue now is that the last clicked entry remains selected and that there does not seem to be a clean way to avoid this:

[image]

Is there any proper MVVM way without code behind to avoid this behavior?! Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records, I did not find a decent way to achieve the aforementioned clearing of the last selected item in the list.

So I proceeded as follows (to me it feels more like a dirty hack/workaround...):

I bound the `SelectedItem` property of the `RibbonGallery` to a property of the `ViewModel` for the sole purpose of resetting this value to null...

```xml
<RibbonGallery Grid.Row         = "1"
               CanUserFilter    = "False"
               Command          = "{Binding cmdOpenRecent}" 
               CommandParameter = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}"
               SelectedItem     = "{Binding RecentSelectedLessonBook}"

               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto">

    <RibbonGalleryCategory Background   = "Transparent" 
                           ItemsSource  = "{Binding RecentLessonBooks}">

        <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>

        <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="proptypes:SettingRecentLessonBook">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding bookName}" ToolTip="{Binding bookFolder}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>

    </RibbonGalleryCategory>

</RibbonGallery>
```

If there is a better MVVM way of achieving this.... YOU ARE WELCOME! :)